# saving number on Button click

Tags: android, android-studio

this is my java file..i want to save my inputted number by clicking the "Submit" button..Can anyone help me to complete my coding?

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ed1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.no);
    b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String ph  = ed1.getText().toString();
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
            editor.putString(Phone, ph);
            editor.commit();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Thanks",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Toast msg = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    "Succeed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            msg.show();
        }


    });
}}}
```

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for how to properly ask questions

Answer (score 0):

Set up a broadcast receiver with the BOOT_COMPLETED action. And also use the RECIEVE_BOOT_COMPLETED permission. Implement your logic in the receiver or in a service if you feel that is appropriate. Next time please do an internet search before asking a question here because the solution is all over the web.

Comment: i tried to find on the net..but couldnt find..I wanna link my secondary phone number and the location will be sent to the following phone number on restart